# Accessing outside of class's namespace inside class method?

Tags: c++, namespaces, struct, scope, typedef

I have a header resource that I'm making use of that defines a struct called

```
typedef struct { ... } Mii;
```

Now, in my own program, I'm writing a wrapper class that uses this struct privately and internally for its own operations, so I put my class inside my program's namespace to avoid conflict.

```
namespace CMii {
    class Mii {
        ...
        void doSomething();
    };
}
```

Now, I can refer to my wrapper class by CMii::Mii. Now, inside the implementation of doSomething:

```
void CMii::Mii::doSomething() {
    Mii m; 
    ...
}
```

The compiler thinks I'm referring to CMii::Mii. How can I tell the compiler I want to use the struct?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
::Mii m
```

Comment: Thank you! Didn't realize you could refer to the top namespace this way.